# .forEach only repeating last object in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, ejs

I want to show all the records that are saved in my MongoDB table on the front-end(ejs). Im using the .forEach function to loop through all the records but I can only see the last field on the frontend repeated many times. Below is the code.

```
<% Object.values(products).forEach(product => { %>
    <tr>
        <td class="border px-3 py-2"><%= products.title %></td>
        <td class="border px-3 py-2"><%= products.description %></td>
        <td class="border px-3 py-2"><%= products.category %></td>
        <td class="border px-3 py-2"><%= products.usdPrice %></td>
    </tr>
    <% }) %>
```

express route:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
try{
    products = await Product.find()
    res.render('products', {products: products})
    //res.json(products)
}catch(err){
    res.json({message: err})
}
```

})

Comment: Should it not be product.title product.description? Drop the s from the end.

Answer (score 0):

For your express controller logic, use this to fetch ALL your products:

```
products = await Product.find().toArray();
```

Now, you are already passing "products" to your template. So you can simply do this in the template by viewing info for each "product", not "products":

```
<% products.forEach(product => { %>
    <tr>
        <td class="border px-3 py-2"><%= product.title %></td>
        <td class="border px-3 py-2"><%= product.description %></td>
        <td class="border px-3 py-2"><%= product.category %></td>
        <td class="border px-3 py-2"><%= product.usdPrice %></td>
    </tr>
    <% }) %>
```

Comment: its catching an exception

Comment: Please post the exception here.

Comment: {"message":{}} from the catch function below the try block

Comment: What does your Product.find() return?

Comment: all the records in the database